# SQL Query to Identify Missing Records (NOT IN subquery)

Tags: sql, subquery, notin

I'm trying to write a query which will return every ID (shared value between both document types 6553 and 6554) for print jobs which generated for document type 6553, but not 6554 - these are meant to always generate together.

I've attempted the following, which takes quite a long time to run and produces a number of values which seems too high to me:

```
select ID from PrintQueueShadow
where DocumentType = '6553'
and CreateDate > getdate() - 7  --No more than 7 days old
and ID not in
(select ID from PrintQueueShadow
where CreateDate > getdate() - 7
and DocumentType = '6554')  --Checking against every ID for Doc Type 6554s sent in the last 7 days
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you share sample inputs and corresponding outputs by updating your question? @oreadwin

Comment: Not really sure what you need here, especially in terms of inputs. The query returns a list of around 1600 ID numbers, and I've been told that this is probably too many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic looks correct, but we can improve upon what you have by using exists logic instead.  Also, we can try suggesting an index which might speed up the query.

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM PrintQueueShadow pqs1
WHERE DocumentType = '6553' AND CreateDate > GETDATE() - 7 AND
      NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM PrintQueueShadow pqs2
          WHERE pqs2.ID = pqs1.ID AND
                CreateDate > GETDATE() - 7 AND 
                DocumentType = '6554'
      );
```

Using `EXISTS` might perform better than `WHERE IN (...)`, as the former lets the database stop searching as soon as it finds a matching record in the subquery.

The above query might benefit from the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON PrintQueueShadow (ID, DocumentType, CreateDate);
```

You may also try permutations of the three columns in the above index.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using self join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PQS_1.ID 
FROM PrintQueueShadow AS PQS_1
LEFT JOIN PrintQueueShadow AS PQS_2
     ON  PQS_1.ID = PQS_2.ID
     AND PQS_2.CreateDate > GETDATE() - 7
     AND PQS_2.DocumentType = '6554' --Checking against every ID for Doc Type 6554s sent in the last 7 days
WHERE PQS_1.DocumentType = '6553'
  AND PQS_1.CreateDate > GETDATE() - 7  --No more than 7 days old
  AND PQS_2.ID IS NULL -- Excluding ID which have been found in Doc Type 6553
```

I've also added `DISTINCT` statement in case if there're duplicates of `ID` in a given `DocumentType`